# ¿Cómo puedo hacer escritura y lectura simultánea de un fichero en c++?

Tags: c++

Estoy creando un programa que permite al usuario introducir nombres y que los guarda dentro de un fichero. Cuando el usuario vuelva a abrir el programa quiero que los nombres, previamente escritos, sigan ahí.

El problema está en que no he encontrado una forma de que mi programa detecte si el archivo existe, y en caso de que no, lo cree, pero en caso de que si, solo lo lea. Lo único que veo es con la librería fstream, pero siempre que se le escribe algo nuevo al archivo se borra lo anterior.

Comment: abre el archivo, guarda el contenido actual en un buffer y luego cuando vayas a guardar el archivo agrega el buffer mas tu modificación, es muy simple la solución...

Answer (score 1):

Si yo fuera tu, lo que haría sería primero abrirlo con `ifstream` para lectura y luego con `ofstream ios::app` para escritura, cuando creas un objeto stream puedes verificar que el archivo se abrió con la funcion is_open

```
ifstream fichero;
fichero.open("fichero.txt");
if (fichero.is_open) std::cout << "El fichero se abrio por lo tanto existe";
else
{
std::cout << "no abrio, probablemente no exista";
ofstream otro_stream;
otro_stream.open("fichero.txt"); // alli se crea el fichero 
otro_stream <<"escribe esto";
}
```

Sin embargo tu pregunta dice que lo quieres abrir para escritura; lo debes hacer con `fstream`declaras un objeto de esta clase lo abres, lo lees y lo escribes

Answer (score 0):

> Estoy creando un programa que permite al usuario introducir nombres y que los guarda dentro de un fichero para cuando el usuario vuelva a abrir el programa, los nombres previamente escritos sigan ahí.

No veo dónde está la simultaneidad que reclamas en el título.

> Con la libreria fstream, pero siempre que se le escribe algo nuevo al archivo se borra lo anterior.

Ese es el comportamiento por defecto de [`ofstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)<sup>1</sup>, en caso de no especificar el [modo de apertura](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), si quieres que al abrir se conserven los datos anteriores y escribir a partir de éstos, especifica el modo [`app`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)<sup>2</sup> en el constructor de `ofstream`:

```
std::ofstream nombres("nombres.txt", std::ios::app);
//                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

<sup>1</sup>`o`utput`f`ile`stream`, flujo de salida a archivo.

<sup>2</sup>`app`end, añadir.